# How to append vector matrix in C++?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a struct vector "array" that's looks like

```
struct competitor
{
    vector<string> name;
    vector<int> points;
};
```

and I have a file which contains names and 10 pieces of result point I would like to read in, but I can't append to vector. I can't read it

```
int i = 0;
string tmp;

while(!x.eof())
{
   getline(x, tmp, '\t');
   t[i].name.push_back(tmp);
   // tmp >> t[i].name;
   cout << tmp << endl;

   for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
   {
       x >> tmp;
       t[i].pontok.push_back(tmp);
   }
   i++;
}
```

Comment: [`while (!eof())` is wrong.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<11;i++)` that means 11 iterations, not 10. It would be 10 if you start from 1.

Comment: Attempt tracing your code, in other words execute it "on the paper" step be step in order to debug it. Be very careful on loop times, eof checks, and even variable correct initializations. Fix each step you find buggy, till the code is bug free.

Comment: But i don't know that how long is the file, but i know that there are name and 10 points

Comment: @MariusBancila: No, it's 10. It would be 11 if it said i<=11.

Comment: yes but i take off the names befor the program step in for. the files separate by tab  and a "split tab" the names and after remaind the numbers

Comment: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 . Count it yourself. There's eleven of it...

Comment: `tmp` is a string, but you want to push it back to int vector. Why?

Comment: Also there is a member naming mismatch in your code : points<->pontok. Please, check your code once more.

Comment: it's unified in my file, but i have a problem to APPEND!!!
Code blocks has a problem that no matching fuction for call to 'std::vector<int, std allocator<int> >::push_...